# How to clear relationship property for Laravel Eloquent Model?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

There are two models

```
item
image
```

and there is `hasMany` relationship between them (item has many images)

I need to delete all images of item, then create new images and pass the item with new images to view.

```
$item->images()->delete();
foreach ($this->new_images as $public_id){
    $item->images()->create([
         'public_id' => $public_id
    ]);
}
```

However in this case I missed the `deleted` Eloquent event on deleted images which is important in this case. I tried to delete them seperately:

```
$item->images->each(function($image){
    $image->delete();
});
foreach ($this->new_images as $public_id){
    $item->images()->create([
         'public_id' => $public_id
    ]);
}
```

And now the `deleted` event in fired however the old images are not removed from `$item`. They are actually deleted from DB but the `$item` is not updated (as it was in case of `$item->images()->delete()`) and still holds references.

Is there a way to clear the relation? In pseudo-code:

```
//delete images one-by-one
$item->images = null;
// now add the new images
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reload images data with:

```
$item->load('images');
```

Comment: Adding `$item->images = [];` between deletion of old one and creation on new one did not work. However addding `$item->load('image')` right after creation assured that the $item is up to date.

Comment: @KārlisJanisels thanks for the feedback, I've updated the answer.